# Qt slot, no matching function for call

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm quite new to Qt. I wanted to create a simple application where there's triangle generated using OpenGL and three push buttons changing that triangle colour.

Here's my code:

In MainWindow.h I declare slots:

```
public slots:
void redButton(Widget w);
void greenButton(Widget w);
void blueButton(Widget w);
```

They change colour using function in Widget class:

```
void MainWindow::redButton(Widget w)
{
    w.setColor(red);
}
```

In widget.h I have:

```
class Widget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);

    QSize minimumSizeHint() const;
    QSize sizeHint() const;

    enum color
    {
        red,
        green,
        blue
    };

    enum color c;

    void setColor(enum color color1);

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int width, int height);

};
```

And function setColor looks like this:

```
void Widget::setColor(enum color color1)
{
    c = color1;
}
```

Unfortunately I get an error saying:

> no matching function forr call to 'Widget::setColor(QPushButton*&)'
>   w.setColor(red);

//Same goes for blue and green
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your function declaration

```
 void Widget::setColor(enum color color1);
```

obviously doesn't match your calls for

```
 void Widget::setColor(QPushButton*&);
```

Certainly none of those `QPushButton` instances, establishes a valid instance of `enum color`, thus you get those compiler errors.

Comment: Oh yeah! Thanks! I forgot that I named my buttons same way as enum elements. I see it. But now I have an error sayong 'red was not declared in this scope'. How should I declare it?

Comment: @user30935 Provide enums at separate header files, and `#include` them whenever needed.

Comment: OK, now I have one more error:
E:\Programy\Qt\5.3\mingw482_32\include\QtOpenGL\qgl.h:457: error: 'QGLWidget::QGLWidget(const QGLWidget&)' is private
     Q_DISABLE_COPY(QGLWidget)
                    ^